# No Json returned

Tags: json, http, go, goroutine

I am trying to use a Go routine to return back Json data to a request. When I test1(w,r) without the "go" my code works. When I use test1() as a go routine I dont get any json data back. Why is this happening?

```
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/test", viewdata)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func viewdata(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    go test1(w, r)

}

func test1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

   // example struct
    ll := sample{
        "city",
        12,
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json, _ := json.Marshal(ll)
    w.Write(json)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code flow, I do not see a point of using goroutine. May you have some reason.

Let's get to your question. Currently your request gets completed before the goroutine that was started by `viewdata` handler. So, you have to use `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for goroutine `test1` to complete the execution.

Your update code:

```
func viewdata(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go test1(w, r, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}

func test1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    ll := sample{
        "city",
        12,
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json, _ := json.Marshal(ll)
    w.Write(json)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http handler is already spawned as goroutine. So you don't need to spawn your goroutine.

```
func viewdata(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ll := sample{
        "city",
        12,
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.NewEncoder(w).Encode(ll)
}
```